# Pasting an image into a new image as a selection in Photoshop CS 4?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-cs4

I have an image that I have copied & then I have pasted it into another new image I created that is twice the size; however when I paste it into the new image it just pastes in the middle & I am unable to move the image around to where I want to place it.

So I am wondering how is it possible that when I paste it into the image it is automatically selcted so that I can move it around?

Thanks!

Comment: I mean, you *can* just `ctrl` click the new layer and it automatically selects your pasted content.

Comment: You can select Move Tool using keypress `v` then you should be able to move the pasted layer using arrow keys of by dragging it via mouse.

Comment: Ok.... I found out I needed to make a new layer before pasting it & then I was able to use your ideas above to move it. Thanks.

Comment: Not a thing. You can answer your own question and accept it in two days or let either Kush or me answer the question so it is closed.

Comment: Fine by me if you answer it :)